# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I am working with C# Form based application with Access as DB.

And getting this error

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Request_Data = 12/15/2010 12:00:00 AM AND User_ID = '1''.
```

On this query.

```
String sql = "Select * From Requests WHERE Request_Data = 12/15/2010 12:00:00 AM AND User_ID = '1'";
```

What's wrong in this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you need <strike>quotes</strike> hashes around the datetime:

`String sql = "Select * From Requests WHERE Request_Data = #12/15/2010 12:00:00 AM# AND User_ID = '1'";`

Comment: Request_Data is of Date/Time datatype and don't require quotes. Though I have tried it and it give incorrect datatype error.

Comment: Perhaps #12/15/2010 12:00:00 AM# instead.

Comment: It would be great if you edited your answer to show the correct answer, that is, with hash (#) not quotes (').