# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
string sqlStatement = "select ID, Checkintime, RoomPrice, OrderNo from Orders where RoomType='" + selectedRoom.Key + "' and RoomNumber=" + selectedRoom.Value + " and Checkintime>="+dateOnly+" and CheckinTime<'"+endingTime+"'"; 

myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, myAccessConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Orders");
```

I have syntax error in the SQL statement line but I am not sure what went wrong that caused an syntax exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446319/syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression)

Comment: Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

Short fix:
change

```
Checkintime>="+dateOnly+"
```

to

```
Checkintime>='"+dateOnly+"'
```

(you forgot the tick marks in the first reference to `Checkintime`)

Much better:
**Use a parameterized query**